# Unexpected result when using command line arguments to look for file with symbol

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to write a script that accepts 2 command line arguments e.g. one a directory name the other a symbol (any symbol can be $,£,^,* and so on). It should then check if the directory has a file name that has that symbol and if it doesn't add the symbol to the directory.

So if I looked for a directory called `testDir` as first argument and had a `*` as the second argument it would check for files in that directory to see if there is that symbol in a file and if there wasn't the directory would now be called `testDir*`.

Here is a bit of code that I'm trying to develop on.

```
a1=$1  
  symbol=$(ls $a1 | grep $2)

   if [ "$symbol" != "" ]
     then
     echo "file has Symbol"

   else
     echo "The symbol was added to directory"
     mv $a1 $1$2
    fi
```

It seemed to work OK with the `@` symbol so I believe its been effected by the special characters. Is there any way to try escape special characters but also work with non-special characters?

Comment: You forgot quotes around `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: It would be much easier for us to help you if you also explained what exactly you are trying to do. Your approach is very strange so I'm not sure what your objective here is.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is [never a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to parse the output of `ls` when looking for file names. That will break on any strange characters including a simple space. The best way around that is to use [shell globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) or `find` instead.

Your next issue is that you're not quoting the variables which means that special characters are expanded before the `mv` command is run. A working example of your script would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if find "$1" -print0 | grep -z "$2" >/dev/null
then
    echo "file has Symbol" 
else
    echo  "The symbol was added to directory" 
    echo mv "$1" "$1$2" 
fi
```

**WARNING** : I have no idea why you would want to do that. It would. for example attempt to move a directory into a subdirectory of itself and that will fail. I suspect an XY problem here and would suggest you edit your question to explain what you are really trying to do.

Comment: I will explain in detail what I am looking for. I want to add a symbol to a directory that I use in the first command line argument if no file or sub directory contain that symbol (which is supplied in the second argument) So if I ran the script  `./script test $`                                                      It would check the directory test and look through its files & sub directories to see if any of them contain the symbol ($) in its name. So if a sub directory in the directory test called testb had a filed called do$$ it would echo the file has the symbol.

Comment: But if no file had the symbol in a file or directory it would echo added to directory and rename the directory in our example test was the directory so it would now be called test$.